# how to run cloned/github remote react native app, err msg no android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

NOTES: Im new in react native and i see there are so many approaches and with this error i thought the developer who built this app build it differently from what i learn so i don't understand why he didn't put the android folder

so i just joined a project and im going to run the apps in my pc by cloning it from github but when i try to `npx react-native run-android` it failed to run and the log is like this

```
error Android project not found. Are you sure this is a React Native project? 
If your Android files are located in a non-standard location (e.g. not inside 'android' folder), 
consider setting project.android.sourceDir option to point to a new location.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

the folder structure is like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error message says there's no "android" folder. There's no "android" folder. What more do you need from an error message? In any case Git and GitHub are irrelevant, you just need to have any required files stored in any required locations.

Comment: question updated

Comment: You may need to ask whoever stored that project on GitHub. Perhaps it's not intended to be an Android project, or perhaps the Android parts of it are stored elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files show that the project is created with [Expo](https://docs.expo.dev/). Specifically, you have a [managed expo project](https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/#managed-workflow).

`npx react-native run-android` would compile an android app from source, with Expo's managed workflow that's not needed. You will need the [Expo Go App](https://expo.dev/client).

Expo also comes with its own commands to start the bundler. Instead of running `npx react-native ...` make use of the expo-cli running: `npx expo start`

However, in the `package.json` there is very likely a `script` called `start`. In that case, it's easier for you to run `npm start`.

After running this command the expo console opens. Here you can press `a` to open the app using expo go (or instructions on how to do so).

Alternatively, you can run `npx expo run:android` to start the expo go app on android yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you are using an expo, there is a folder named .expo-shared, after

```
npm install
```

Try to run

```
npm start
```

or

```
expo start
```

or

```
npx expo start
```

something like this will appear:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7pKQ.jpg
after that go to the terminal, open the emulator in you computer and click on the terminal and press 'a',